$G$ is solvable and $H \trianglelefteq G$. Does $H$'s chain contain a tail end of $G$'s chain?
Let $G$ be a solvable group and let $H \lhd G$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. As $G$ is solvable, then $H$ is solvable. One equivalence of solvability (for $H$) is: there exists a chain of normal subgroups $N_i$ wherein
$$1 = N_1 \trianglelefteq N_2 \trianglelefteq \dots \trianglelefteq N_k = H \tag{1}$$
where $N_i/N_{i-1}$ is abelian and $N_i$ is normal in $H$. Now, since $G$ is solvable, $G$ also has a chain of subnormal subgroups with abelian quotients that are themselves also normal in $G$. Is it necessarily the case that the equation in $(1)$ is the tail end of $G$'s chain of normal subgroups? Visually speaking, the question is whether
$$\underbrace{1 = N_1 \trianglelefteq N_2 \trianglelefteq \dots \trianglelefteq N_k = H}_{(1)} \trianglelefteq N_{k+1} \trianglelefteq \dots \trianglelefteq N_m = G \tag{2}$$
is the composition series of which we speak when we say $G$ is solvable (or at least one of the chains, if there is more than one).

Is (1) a subchain of an abelian series for $G$? Yes. Just bolt on a chain for $G/H$ to any given series for $H$. But the $N_i$ are normal in $N_{i+1}$ in general, there is no requirement for them to be normal in $H$ or $G$, as you want.

Note that "composition series" has a technical meaning: it means that the series is subnormal (each $N_i$ is assumed normal in $N_{i+1}$, but not necessarily in the whole group),, and each quotient $N_{i+1}/N_i$ is simple. So you do not want to say "composition series" series.

Given the definition you are using, there is always a chain of subgroups $N_i$ of $H$, normal in $H$, with each $N_{i+1}/N_i$ abelian, that will be the tail of a similar chain for $G$ itself... but not every series of $H$ is the tail of a series for  $G$.
For an example of the latter, consider $G=A_4$ and $H=\{e,(12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$. Then $H$ has a normal series given by
$$\{e\} \triangleleft \{e,(12)(34)\} \triangleleft H,$$
but since $\{e,(12)(34)\}$ is not normal in $A_4$, there is no way to complete this chain into a series for $G$ in which each subgroup is normal in $G$.
However, when $G$ is solvable there is always a chain that works. Namely we can take the derived series of $H$; since the terms of the derived series of $H$ are characteristic in $H$, they will be normal in $G$ (given that $H$ is normal in $G$). Then we can take series of normal subgroups with consecutive abelian quotients of $G/H$ and lift it to $G$ to get a series for $G$ in which each term is normal in $G$, and the quotients are all abelian.
(And yes, in general there are lots of series for a group; though there is a canonical series, which is the derived series.)

Not necessarily. Consider the quaternion group $Q_8=\langle i,j,k\rangle$. Obviously $Q_8$ is solvable (since it is a $2$-group). Now, take $H=\langle i\rangle\unlhd G$ and consider the chain
$$1\unlhd\langle -1\rangle\unlhd\langle j\rangle\unlhd Q_8.$$
